# How to read a csv in pandas with a missing delimiter (or - with additional delimiters)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-cleaning

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv_one = """\
one;two;three
1;2;3;
4;5;6;
"""
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv), sep=";")
```

This data looks as:

```
   one  two  three
1    2    3    NaN
4    5    6    NaN
```

The desired result is:

```
   one  two  three
    1    2    3    
    4    5    6
```

I *could* manually edit the csv, but I don't really want to have to do that if possible.

In `R` the function `read_delim` can manage this with something along the lines of `read_delim( <path>, ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working `index_col=False` parameter:

```
csv = """\
one;two;three
1;2;3;
4;5;6;
"""
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv), sep=";", index_col=False)
print (df1)
   one  two  three
0    1    2      3
1    4    5      6
```

Comment: thank you ( I thought I had tried this - but I fear i might have edited the csv at source by this point), is there any way for pandas to detect whether this should be required? Or, will i have to write a function that will check the number of delimiters in the rows of the CSV prior to loading the data

Comment: @baxx - I think by default is `index_col=None`, so unfortuantely in this type of data is necessary `index_col=False` - [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) - `Note: index_col=False can be used to force pandas to not use the first column as the index, e.g. when you have a malformed file with delimiters at the end of each line.`